# Invertibility of sum of an invertible matrix and a nonnegative diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an invertible matrix such that $A+D$ is also invertible for every diagonal matrix $D$ with positive diagonal entries. I need to prove that For any diagonal matrix $E$ with nonnegative diagonal entries, $A+E$ is invertible. I tried doing the following:
Consider $A+E$ = $A+E+I-I$. Since $E+I$ is a diagonal matrix with positive diagonal entries, $A+E+I$ is invertible by our hypothesis. But after that I dont know how to proceed. Please help me to solve this!!

Answer (score 1):

You can consider a sequence of diagonal matrices E_n with positive diagonal entries  such that lim E_n = E. Then, for each n, there is B_n, such that (A+E_n)*B_n=I. If lim B_n = B, taking limits we have (A+E)*B=I.

Comment: Here limit $B_{n}$ exists by the continuity of inverse function right?!

Comment: Actually I'm not sure. But since B_n is a limited sequence, it has a convergent subsequence and this one gets the job done.

Comment: @tetsuzan How do you prove that $B_n$ is a bounded sequence? I can argue that $f:M\to M^{-1}$ is a homeomorphism, and since the sequence $A+E_n$ is bounded, so is $B_n$.

Comment: no idea... let's keep the homeomorphism argument. lol (I was thinking that the norm had some kind of multiplicative property but I realized it hasn't).